# SAML SSO integration with Struts 2 based application to make it work as Service Provider

Tags: java, spring-security, struts2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I need to integrate SAML SSO in my struts 2 based application as SP with ADFS as IDP. How to integrate it without Spring Security? If Spring security is best option, how to do that in Struts2 based application?

Comment: put apache in front of it and use this https://www.shibboleth.net/products/service-provider/

Comment: What is the application server where your web application will be deployed?